Google Workspace Admin SDK Email Log Search Reports API: How to retrieve email delivery status?
I'm using the Google Workspace Admin SDK Reports API - Email Log Search in Node.js to retrieve email logs for messages sent from my domain. I'm able to get details like:

Sender email
Recipient email
External Message ID
Timestamp (Start Date - End Date)

However, I cannot find any field or property that provides the delivery status of the email (e.g., whether it was delivered, bounced, failed, etc.). Though I can see the delivery status in admin console:

My Questions:

Does the Google Workspace Admin SDK provide delivery status information for emails? If so, where can I find it?

If the API does not include this information, is there any other Google API or method that can be used to determine the delivery status of emails?


I’ve gone through the documentation for Email Log Search, but I can’t find any reference to retrieving the delivery status of an email.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:​
const { google } = require("googleapis"););
const credentials = require('../file-path-to-creds.json'););

// Scopes for Gmail API access
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly', 'https://mail.google.com/', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];

const AuthClient = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({ credentials, scopes, clientOptions:{ subject: 'user@randomDomain.com' } });

const admin = google.admin({ version: "reports_v1", auth: AuthClient }); });

async function getGmailReports() {
    const {afterDate, beforeDate} = getDateRangeQuery(14);
    let senders = [];
    let recievers = [];
    let messageIds = [];
   
    await admin.activities.list({ userKey: 'all', applicationName: 'admin',
        eventName: 'EMAIL_LOG_SEARCH',
        startTime: afterDate, endTime: beforeDate,
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) { return console.error('API returned an error : ', err); }
        if (!res.data.items || res.data.items.length === 0) { return console.log('No Email log search reports found!'); }

        res.data.items.forEach((list, idx) => {
          list.events.forEach((event, indx) => {
            event.parameters.forEach((param, index) => {
                if (param.name === 'EMAIL_LOG_SEARCH_SENDER') { senders.push({ email: param.value, index: `${idx}-${indx}-${index}` }); }
                if (param.name === 'EMAIL_LOG_SEARCH_RECIPIENT') { recievers.push({ email: param.value, index: `${idx}-${indx}-${index}` }); }
                if (param.name === 'EMAIL_LOG_SEARCH_MSG_ID') { messageIds.push({ id: param.value, index: `${idx}-${indx}-${index}` }); }
            });
          });  
        });
})};        

function getDateRangeQuery(days = 2) {
    let now = new Date();
    const beforeDate = new Date(now).toISOString();
    const afterDate = new Date(now.setDate(now.getDate() - days)).toISOString();
    return {afterDate, beforeDate};
};

module.export = getGmailReports;

Let me know if you need additional information.
